# Perl MySQL Fulltext Search

Tags: mysql, perl, full-text-search, dbi

I'm new to this site.

I have the following code to search against three columns with fulltext index. (searchdatabase.title, searchdatabase.keywords, searchdatabase.description)

```
$SQL_QUERY=<<__CURSOR_1__;
select distinct url, keywords, description, title from searchdatabase 
where match ( searchdatabase.title, searchdatabase.keywords, 
searchdatabase.description ) against ('$datasent' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
order by authority_rank desc, rank desc limit 10 offset $page;
__CURSOR_1__


$dbh = DBI -> connect ($dns, $username, $password) 
or &Error("Can not connect to database.");

$cursor = $dbh->prepare( "$SQL_QUERY" );
$cursor->execute;
```

With my limited knowledge of Perl fulltext search and SQL, I have the following code before the above code to do some SQL injection prevention and make spaces "+" in order to search.

```
$datasent =~ s/ / +/g;
$datasent =~ s/　/ +/g;
$datasent =~ s/\n//g;
$datasent =~ s/<//g;
$datasent =~ s/\x00//g;
$datasent =~ s/\r//g;
$datasent =~ s/\x1a//g;
$datasent =~ s/\;//g; 
$datasent =~ s/\*//g; 
$datasent =~ s/\'//g; 
$datasent =~ s/\"//g;
```

Is this the right way to do this?
I have a feeling something's wrong with making spaces into "+"...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've edited the code so that it fits. Is it better now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DBI's placeholders](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values) are the way to go here. It will take care of escaping stuff for you.

```
my $sql = <<'CURSOR_1';
select distinct url, keywords, description, title
from searchdatabase where
match ( searchdatabase.title, searchdatabase.keywords, searchdatabase.description )
against (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
order by authority_rank desc, rank desc limit 10 offset $page;
CURSOR_1
```

You basically put `?` into the query. When you call it, pass the parameters into `execute`.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$cursor->execute( $datasent) ;
```

For `$page` this will not work because it's not part of the WHERE clause. Instead, you should just make sure that it contains a number in case it comes from outside.

```
die 'offset needs to be numeric' if $page =~ /\D/;
```

---

Since you're a new user, here are a few notes about your code:

- always `use strict` and `use warnings` – they make your life easier
- then declare your variables with `my`
- `$ALL_CAPS` variables are usually used for globals variables in Perl
- in a DBI context, statement handles are usually named `$sth`
- don't use the ampersand in `&foo()`, it doesn't do what you think
- you don't need to put single variables into double quotes for interpolation

Comment: Thank you very much, making the limit and offset have placeholder as well as placeholder in BOOLEAN MODE did the trick!

Comment: @TsubasaKato glad I could help. Please take the [tour] to learn how to accept an answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @simbabque's great suggestions, let me explain the `+` substitution.

A fulltext search `BOOLEAN` mode, by default probably does not do what you expect. "By default (when neither + nor - is specified) the word is optional, but the rows that contain it are rated higher... " See the [Mysql Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

So if your user searches for `red apple` they will get anything with "red" OR "apple" in some priority decided by mysql. Which you may decide is likely not what they want. So in the back end, you can replace the user's search with `+red +apple` which tells mysql to search for "red AND apple".

This is what I have

```
$datasent =~ s/[+\-<>)(]/ /g;     #These have special meaning in the sql search that people probably don't want.
$datasent =~ s/(".*?"|\S+)/+$1/g; #Add '+' for the boolean search and pay attention to quotes.
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant to figure out first. I forgot to add a bit to the $datasent part. I coded `$datasent = "\+$datasent";` in front of the + substitution lines. Is this correct?

Comment: In similar code I have, I first strip out all the '+' and '-' symbols, then re-add them, paying attention to quoted strings. I can update my answer with that info, but can't get to it right now.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try to figure out to do like you suggested.